# Make an API call while displaying a splash screen in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I know how to make a splash screen in Swift. But I want to call a function while the splash screen is shown which will make an API call. I tried to do it like this:

```
func showSpinner(actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView){
    actInd.center = self.view.center
    actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
    actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    self.view.addSubview(actInd)
    actInd.startAnimating()
}

func stopSpinner(actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView){
    actInd.stopAnimating()
}

func getStrings(){
    var apiParams = NSDictionary() as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    apiParams["p1"] = "2"
    apiParams["p2"] = "3"
    callBaseApi("getstrings", "http://swt.com/xyz/", apiParams)
}

func callBaseApi(path: String, basePath: String, params: NSDictionary){
    println("123")           //<- This is not getting printed
    var jsonSerializationError = NSError?()
    var jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &jsonSerializationError)
    var url = basePath + path
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = jsonData
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error = NSError?()
        let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary
        if (jsonResult != nil) {
            // process jsonResult
            println("Result came")
        } else {
            // couldn't load JSON, look at error
        }
    })
}

override func viewDidLoad(){
    ...
    var actInd = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    self.showSpinner(actInd)
    self.getStrings()
    self.stopSpinner(actInd)
}
```

As you can see, getStrings is calling callBaseApi which is not printing anything. If I call the `self.getStrings` function and run the code in the simulator, I see a black screen. But, if I call the `self.getStrings` function inside `dispatch_async` like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    self.getStrings()
})
```

I get to see the splash screen, but the getStrings function does not seem to make any API call. Where am I going wrong? Please help.